# Consolidating GNU C's and C23's deprecated function attribute

Tags: c, gcc, clang, c-preprocessor, c23

The problem I am facing when using the below macro

```
// Assume that __GNUC__ or __clang__ is defined. 

#if defined(__has_c_attribute)
    #if __has_c_attribute(deprecated)
        #define ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED(...)          [[deprecated(__VA_ARGS__)]]
    #endif    /* deprecated */
#else  
    #define ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED(...)              __attribute__((deprecated(__VA_ARGS__)))
#endif    /* __has_c_attribute */
```

is that `__attribute__((deprecated()))` and `__attribute__((deprecated))` are equivalent, but `[[deprecated()]]` and `[[deprecated]]` are not.

The `#else` block works correctly when called with either of these:

```
ATTRIB_DEPRECATED()
ATTRIB_DEPRECATED("privat")
```

because GNU C allows the parameter-list of the attribute to be empty.

But when compiling with `std=c2x`, the `#if` block does not, and fails with:

```
deprecated.c:12:14: error: parentheses must be omitted if attribute argument list is empty
```

Is there a way I can get the same code to work with C23 as well?

It'd also be nicer if I could write:

```
ATTRIB_DEPRECATED
```

instead of:

```
ATTRIB_DEPRECATED()
```

if no argument was to be provided.

For a MRE:

```
// Assume that __GNUC__ or __clang__ is defined. 

#if defined(__has_c_attribute) 
    #if __has_c_attribute(deprecated)
        #define ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED(...)          [[deprecated(__VA_ARGS__)]]
    #endif
#else  
    #define ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED(...)              __attribute__((deprecated(__VA_ARGS__)))
#endif    /* __has_c_attribute */

ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED() int min(int a, int b)
{
    return a < b ? a : b;
}

int main() {
    return min(10, 20);
}
```

The above code would only compile f `__has_c_attribute` was not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have to have two separate macros for that

```
#if defined(__has_c_attribute) 
    #if __has_c_attribute(deprecated)
        #define ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED          [[deprecated]]
        #define ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATEDR(...)    [[deprecated(#__VA_ARGS__)]]
    #endif
#else  
    #define ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED              __attribute__((deprecated))
    #define ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATEDR(...)        __attribute__((deprecated))
#endif    /* __has_c_attribute */



ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATEDR(this is test) int min(int a, int b)
{
    return a < b ? a : b;
}

ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED int max(int a, int b)
{
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

int main() {
    return min(max(10,20), max(10, 20));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/8arY74Gsd

Answer (score 1):

Just VA_OPT it.

```
#define ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED(...)  [[deprecated __VA_OPT__( (__VA_ARGS__) )]]

ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED()
ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED("bla")
```

Below is without VA_OPT. First we take code from https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/detect-empty-macro-arguments/ . Then we add some overload helper to overload based on the return of `ISEMPTY()`. Each overload, just adds the argument or not.

```
#define _ARG16(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14, _15, ...) _15
#define HAS_COMMA(...) _ARG16(__VA_ARGS__, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)
#define _TRIGGER_PARENTHESIS_(...) ,
 
#define ISEMPTY(...)                                                    \
_ISEMPTY(                                                               \
          /* test if there is just one argument, eventually an empty    \
             one */                                                     \
          HAS_COMMA(__VA_ARGS__),                                       \
          /* test if _TRIGGER_PARENTHESIS_ together with the argument   \
             adds a comma */                                            \
          HAS_COMMA(_TRIGGER_PARENTHESIS_ __VA_ARGS__),                 \
          /* test if the argument together with a parenthesis           \
             adds a comma */                                            \
          HAS_COMMA(__VA_ARGS__ (/*empty*/)),                           \
          /* test if placing it between _TRIGGER_PARENTHESIS_ and the   \
             parenthesis adds a comma */                                \
          HAS_COMMA(_TRIGGER_PARENTHESIS_ __VA_ARGS__ (/*empty*/))      \
          )

#define PASTE5(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4) _0 ## _1 ## _2 ## _3 ## _4
#define _ISEMPTY(_0, _1, _2, _3) HAS_COMMA(PASTE5(_IS_EMPTY_CASE_, _0, _1, _2, _3))
#define _IS_EMPTY_CASE_0001 ,

// -----------------------------

#define CONCAT(a, b)  a##b
#define XCONCAT(a, b)  CONCAT(a, b)

#define ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED1()  \
        [[deprecated]]
#define ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED0(...)  \
        [[deprecated(__VA_ARGS__)]]
#define ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED(...)  \
        XCONCAT(ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED, ISEMPTY(__VA_ARGS__))(__VA_ARGS__)


ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED()
ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED("bla")
```

Note passing an empty `()` list for macro with `(...)` is *technically* non-conforming and breaking [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3p4](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3p4) . But no one cares.